# $v_result -ne 0 meaning

Tags: bash, shell-script

Can someone please explain what does the below condition and what does -ne means.

I need to write a script to automate a process.

```
if [ $v_result -ne 0 ] ; then
        v_status="Failed"
else
     v_status="success"
```

Answer (score 4):

The code should double quote the expansion of `$v_result` in the test, and the `if` statement lacks a `fi` after the last line.

The `-ne` test is an arithmetic comparison that tests whether the integer value on the left is *not equal* to the integer value on the right.  If the test succeeds (`$v_result` is not zero), the variable `v_status` is set to the string `Failed`, otherwise it is set to the string `success`.

The `-ne` test is documented in the manual for the `[` and `test` utilities, as well in the manual of your shell.  It's also a standard test operator [described by the POSIX standard for the `test` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 1):

`v_result` is a variable, and `$v_result` is how the shell expands (substitutes its value) this variable. `-ne` is an "arithmetic binary operator" to be applied to integer items in "conditional expressions", returning TRUE if its arguments are not equal. All this can be found in the man page of your shell (e.g. `man bash`)

Answer (score 1):

`-ne` means "Not Equal".
You can find more info about those operators in [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)